# Why isn't memcache caching working after I upgrade Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I recently upgraded my Rails application to 5.2 and couldn't figure out why my caching no longer expired. I narrowed down the problem to the cache key change that allows [recyclable cache keys](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/29092).

This was my configuration:

```
config.load_defaults 5.2
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

view:

```
<% cache product do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the issue and wanted to share it in case anyone else gets stuck! The problem is with the `config.cache_store = :dalli_store`. The dalli_store **does not support** recyclable cache keys, so you have to change it to the mem_cache_store:

`config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store`

I hope this helps someone!